# Does firestore's fast performance remain fast in all cases, even if there are millions of subscribers to the application?

Tags: firebase, flutter, performance, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Does firestore's fast performance remain fast in all cases, even if there are millions of subscribers to the application?

```
        .get() 
        .delete() 
        .set()
        .update()
        .exists?
        .snapshot()
        .listen
        .where
```

ok ..  I'm developing an app that uses the previous methods , since i still didn't publish my app to stores so my app has no any users yet , while i am  developing my app the previous methods is so fast response with `Firestore` but what if my app has millions of users lets say 10 millions , high traffic
and lets say my database in Firestore has millions of docs

i have read that firstore can hold 1 millions simultaneous connection , But regardless of breaking limits

**Will the performance remain the same before and after users come? in case it didn't break any limits**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On their website it says that auto scales very well.
source: https://cloud.google.com/architecture/building-scalable-apps-with-cloud-firestore
Now of course latency might differ from where you selected your server but google has you covered for that too.
source: https://cloud.google.com/architecture/building-scalable-apps-with-cloud-firestore#redundancy_and_availability
If you have many more users it will of course cost you a bit more.
source: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing

Comment: thanks , yes i read it , but still the person who has experiment his answer gonna be the best , i hope someone from google employee answer my question or who has real experiment !